Angular TemplateRef in web component
If we create a webcomponent in Angular, how to consume Input that takes TemplateRef?
For example the following component ist converted to a web component
@component({
selector:"app-lorem",
....
})
export class LoremComponent{

@Input()
ipsum: TemplateRef<any>

....
}

Now in react or in js App its being used as:
...imports here...

<app-lorem> </app-lorem>

<template> Hello world </template>


So the web component is working well but there ist no way to pass template to app-lorem. Moreover i think template can not be assigned to TemplateRef. Any Help here?

Just pass ref to it as value
<app-lorem [ipsum]="myTemplate"> </app-lorem>

<template #myTemplate> Hello world </template>


your suggestion is for angular environment. element ref with # works only in Angular not in react. moreover template can not passed to TemplateRef

"Angular TemplateRef in web component",so....
